# javascript json object and input array name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tree

I have an object for example in the form:

```
{
    "test": {
        "valid": false,
        "children": {
            "a": {
                "valid": false,
                "children": {
                    "1": {
                        "valid": false,
                        "children": {
                            "c": {
                                "valid": false
                            },
                            "d": {
                                "valid": false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ...
                }
            },
            "b": {
                "valid": false
            },
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

I also have an `input` named `name="test[a][1][c]"` or `name="test[b]"`. I need to get the get the `valid` property from the object with the same name of the input. Unfortunately I have no idea how to solve this problem.

My first problem is that I do not know how to divide the input name to a tree. Thank you for help.

edit:

How get universal value 'valid' from the name of INPUT?

I need from the name of INPUT create:
json ['test']['children']['a']['children']['1']['children']['c']['valid']

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: You are missing a layer.  You have object>test>children>a.  You missed the children layer.

Comment: Please demonstration when I have:
var name = $ (this).attr('name') that is: test[a][1][c] and JSON tree is var tree.

How do I get the value valid?

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse` which deserializes `JSON` to produce a JavaScript object or array.

This example uses `JSON.parse` to deserialize `JSON` into the `json_obj` object.

```
var json_obj = JSON.parse(json);
var isValidForC = json_obj.test.children.a.children.1.children.c.valid;
var isValidForB = json_obj.test.children.b.valid;
```

Comment: Thanks, but you need it to work universally by name input.